# Le verbe « radier » est-il couramment synonyme d' « abroger » avec « une loi » etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot, synonymes, droit-et-justice

> L’État de la Géorgie radie la loi sur les arrestations citoyennes. (AP
> sur [Lapresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/2021-05-10/denoncee-comme-raciste/l-etat-de-la-georgie-radie-la-loi-sur-les-arrestations-citoyennes.php))

Le contexte c'est une [loi](https://www.legis.ga.gov/legislation/59726) qui vient changer et dans certains cas abroger<sup>1</sup> certaines dispositions en droit criminel dans l'État.

Le verbe [*radier*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/radier/1) est-il couramment employé comme synonyme d'[*abroger*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abroger) pour une loi, pourquoi l'aurait-on employé ici ; quel synonyme serait plus courant ou meilleur et pourquoi ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Voir par exemple le texte de l'article 2 : « Said title is further amended by repealing in its entirety Article 4 of Chapter 4, relating to arrest by private persons, and designating it as reserved. » (HB 479/AP).</sub>

Answer (score 6):

En France en tout cas, le terme **radier** n'est pas utilisé à ma connaissance pour parler d'abroger une loi.

Radier est généralement utilisé pour parler de rayer, supprimer une nom d'une liste.

> Il a été radié des liste électorales suite à son déménagement

> Il a été radié de pôle emploi après avoir refusé une offre. (sous entendu : radié des listes de demandeur d'emploi)

*Abroger* est vraiment le verbe consacré s'agissant d'une loi, mais on pourrait aussi dire :

- *abolir* (qui porte une connotation positive, et donc s'agissant d'une loi vue comme
  néfaste ou rétrograde)
- *invalider* ou *annuler* si c'est une instance (ex: conseil constitutionnel) qui cause sa suppression.
- *supprimer* : particulièrement s'agissant des dispositions d'une loi/règle ex : "l'obligation de présenter un test PCR à la frontière a été supprimée"